# How to match an json value representing timestamp with floating point?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hamcrest, mockmvc

My REST service returns json like this:

```
{"lastWriteTime":1525507872.123000000 .... }
```

how do I match it in my mockMvc test using `jsonPath` statement?

when I try to use an is or equalTo matcher, like this:

```
andExpect(jsonPath("$.elements[0].lastWriteTime", equalTo(1525507872.123000000)))
```

I keep getting this kind of error in different flavours:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.elements[0].lastWriteTime"
Expected: <1.525507872123E9>
     but: was <1525507872.123000000>
```

casting the value to double or specifying as string doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Comparing floating-point values for equality is always error-prone due to limited precision. I would recommend to calculate the delta between the values and assert that the delta does not exceed a certain threshold. --- The "format" of this timestamp seems strange. Is there a specific reason for the floating point representation instead of a UNIX timestamp or an ISO 8601 string representation?

Comment: yeah I find it strange, too. this seems to be "default" serialization of OffsetDateTime with milliseconds.